# error: pasting "operator" and "+" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a small *Float* class in order to compare floats more easily(as we know, because of the float's precision). So I need to reload almost all operators that *double* has. I find there is too much repeats, such as *operator+*, *operator-*, *operator** and *operator/*. They are similar. So I used a macro to reduce the code length. But when I complie it, it doesn't work. The error is:

```
happy.cc:24:1: error: pasting "operator" and "+" does not give a valid preprocessing token
happy.cc:25:1: error: pasting "operator" and "-" does not give a valid preprocessing token
happy.cc:26:1: error: pasting "operator" and "*" does not give a valid preprocessing token
happy.cc:27:1: error: pasting "operator" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Here is my code:

```
struct Float
{
  typedef double size_type;
  static const size_type EPS = 1e-8;
private:
  size_type x;
public:
  Float(const size_type value = .0): x(value) { }
  Float& operator+=(const Float& rhs) { x += rhs.x; return *this; }
  Float& operator-=(const Float& rhs) { x -= rhs.x; return *this; }
  Float& operator*=(const Float& rhs) { x *= rhs.x; return *this; }
  Float& operator/=(const Float& rhs) { x /= rhs.x; return *this; }
};
#define ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(x) \
inline const Float operator##x(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs)\
{\
  Float result(lhs);\
  return result x##= rhs;\
}
ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(+)
ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(-)
ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(*)
ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(/)
```

And my g++ version is 4.4.3

here is the result of g++ -E:

```
struct Float
{
  typedef double size_type;
  static const size_type EPS(1e-8);
private:
  size_type x;
public:
  Float(const size_type value = .0): x(value) { }
  Float& operator+=(const Float& rhs) { x += rhs.x; return *this; }
  Float& operator-=(const Float& rhs) { x -= rhs.x; return *this; }
  Float& operator*=(const Float& rhs) { x *= rhs.x; return *this; }
  Float& operator/=(const Float& rhs) { x /= rhs.x; return *this; }
};





inline const Float operator+(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs){ Float result(lhs); return result += rhs;}
inline const Float operator-(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs){ Float result(lhs); return result -= rhs;}
inline const Float operator*(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs){ Float result(lhs); return result *= rhs;}
inline const Float operator/(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs){ Float result(lhs); return result /= rhs;}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`##` concatenates tokens to produce a single token; the result must be a valid single token.  You don't need to do this for `operator`, as e.g. `operator+` is not actually a single token.

```
#define ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(x) \
inline const Float operator x(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs)\
{\
  Float result(lhs);\
  return result x##= rhs;\
}
```

Strictly speaking, you *are* producing a single token for the later one.

Preprocessors that are actually textual preprocessors instead of operating during tokenization, such as the one in GCC, are often lenient about this.

Comment: GCC's preprocessor has been integrated with tokenization for approximately 12 years now.

Comment: I would say it's integrated, but not quite in the same way; the fact that it doesn't blow up on trying to produce a single token `operator+` as noted in an earlier comment demonstrates this.

Comment: Visual Studio is lenient about this and GCC is strict and will error out.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `##` in the macro; the tokens pasted have to be identifiers.

The first of the two occurrences in the macro can simply be replaced with a space.  The second is much more problematic.  Superficially, you might get away with:

```
#define ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(x) \
inline const Float operator x(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs)\
{\
  Float result(lhs);\
  return result x= rhs;\
}
```

However, that is most certainly not defined behaviour; the `x` and the `=` are separate preprocessing tokens and won't (should not) be combined into a single token by the pre-processor.  I suspect you will need to use:

```
#define ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(x, y) \
inline const Float operator x(const Float& lhs, const Float& rhs)\
{\
  Float result(lhs);\
  return result y rhs;\
}
ADD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(+, +=)
```